Send an email from Yahoo using VB.net
How to send an email from Yahoo using VB.net?
I tried this
How to send mail from yahoo mail Id in VB.NET or C#.NET code
Try

    Dim m As MailMessage = New MailMessage
    m.From = New MailAddress("MJT7@yahoo.com", "Your Name")
    m.To.Add(New MailAddress("MJT7@yahoo.com", "Recipient Name"))
    m.Subject = "Hello"
    ' Specify an HTML message body
    m.Body = "<html><body><h1>My Message</h1><br>Put the body here.</body></html>"
    m.IsBodyHtml = True
    ' Send the message
    Dim client As SmtpClient = New SmtpClient("smtp.mail.yahoo.com")
    client.Send(m)

Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try

It did not work and I received this message.

And I have tried the code below:
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim fromMail, mailAddress, mailPass As String
        Dim toMail, Subject, Body, confirmationMsg, msgTitle As String

        fromMail = "MJT7 <MJT7@yahoo.com>"
        mailAddress = "MJT7@yahooo.com"
        mailPass = "Password"
        toMail = "MJT7@yahooo.com"
        Subject = "Subject"
        Body = "Body"
        msgTitle = "msgTitle"

        Dim MyMailMessage As New MailMessage()
        Try
            Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
            MyMailMessage.From = New MailAddress(fromMail)
            MyMailMessage.To.Add(toMail)
            MyMailMessage.Subject = Subject
            MyMailMessage.Body = Body


            Dim SMTP As New SmtpClient("smtp.mail.yahoo.com")
            SMTP.Port = 587
            SMTP.EnableSsl = 1


            SMTP.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(mailAddress, mailPass)

            SMTP.Send(MyMailMessage)

            If MsgBox(confirmationMsg, vbOKOnly, msgTitle) = vbOK Then
                Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
            End If




        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub

Also, it did not work and I received this message

PLEASE TAKE INTO CONSIDERATION THAT I USED MY CORRECT EMAIL AND PASSWORD
Sending an email from Yahoo using VB.net

In your second code snippet, you pass an invalid email address ( fromMail ) to the MailAddress ctor. You did it right in the first code. Fix the second snippet and try. You may also want to try port 465.
